# Issue: Object variable or With block variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which should choose two instrument criteria INSTRUMENT = IRS and WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA > 0 and in the table everything is OK, but when you let macros, it gets such an error:

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

[image]

My code:

```
Dim cIndex As Variant
Dim rTable As Range
Dim rCol As Range
Dim rCriteria As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim rCol_A As Range
With wbMe.Sheets("pochodne")
   WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA = "WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA"
   LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
   Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=WYCENA_po_CVA_DVA, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
   Set rCol_A = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=INSTRUMENT, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
   If Not rCol Is Nothing Or rCol_A Is Nothing Then
      .Range("T38").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), ">0", rTable.Columns(rCol_A.Column), "IRS")
       SumCriteria = CVErr(xlErrValue)
   End If
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: @braX here :    .Range("T38").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), ">0", rTable.Columns(rCol_A.Column), "IRS")

Comment: Is `rCol_A` = `Nothing`?

Comment: `If Not rCol Is Nothing And Not rCol_A Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @braX where should i add this ?

Comment: Replace your `If` statement with the one above. I think it is wrong.

Comment: now no issue, But my code does not do anything now :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241027/discussion-between-koniecswiata-and-brax).

Comment: Then your `Find` functions are not finding what you are looking for. I'll ask again... Is `rCol_A` = `Nothing`? That means it didn't find it.

Comment: But if I'm looking for a manually like in the picture, this items finds for me. Where i should add rCol_a = Nothing ? to check if is there somethnig ?

Comment: We can't see where and how `INSTRUMENT` is declared. The same with `SumCriteria`. What does it even do? Always use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of each module. The `Find` method cannot work correctly if your worksheet is filtered. To remove the filter, at the beginning of the With statement you can do: `If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode  = False`.